# How do I prevent my Slack slash command from echoing into the channel?

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, serverless-framework

Using [Serverless](http://serverless.com) and NodeJS, I have a Slack command set up like:

```
/myCommand doStuff
```

When I type `/myCommand doStuff`, the Slack output does this:

> `/myCommand doStuff`
>
> The content of the actual response I want shown goes here.

What I want to do is only have this:

> The content of the actual response I want shown goes here.

without the `/myCommand doStuff` getting echoed.

How do I prevent that from happening?

### Update - adding some code

Here's the actual command:

```
module.exports = () => {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill) {
    fulfill({
      response_type: 'in_channel',
      text: 'some testing text
    });
  });
};
```

Here's the handler:

```
module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  var response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(myCommand()),
  };

  callback(null, response);
};
```

Comment: which computer provider are you using?

Comment: AWS Lambda for hosting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are replying with

```
"response_type": "in_channel"
```

the reply is visible to all users in a channel and it will always copy the command back into the channel. This can not be turned off.

When you are replying with

```
 "response_type": "ephemeral"
```

it is only visible to the user and the command will not be copied back. That is also the default, so you must be using `in_channel` in your script.

See [here](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#responding_to_a_command) for the official documentation on that topic.

Comment: Hey I just want to thank you for all the very useful answers you post on the subject!

Comment: That's close - I just updated the question with what I mean.  I figured that part out.

Comment: what `response_type` are you using in your response? Also, it would be much easier to help you with your problem if you would post your code.

Comment: @eln00b you are using the `ìn_channel` `response type`. As I explained in my answer Slack will then automatically echo the slash command back into the channel. I understand that you want a different behavior, but this can currently not be turned off.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken ok, thanks.  I was trying to override that default behavior.  If you post that as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @eln00b I believe I already did: "the reply is visible to all users in a channel and it will always copy the command back into the channel. This can not be turned off."